# Algorithm to identify extensions/projections off of 2D objects?

Tags: image-processing

I'm using matlab and would like to identify extensions off of 2D objects. For example, it could be an object that is circular in shape but has a long, sharp projection extending from its boundary.

Comment: The definition of shape and extension are too vague to answer.  Please be more specific.

Comment: I managed to archive that by using opencv which is a pretty awesome software with lots of libs and support in python, C, C++, Java, and so on.. It is verry well documented so you should get results pretty fast.